# Non-Apple RAID card for Mac PRO (TOWER)

Tags: raid, mac

I have the following:

- MAC PRO (Model Number: A1186) (PCIe - SLOTS)

At present I am using the software RAID however I wish to move to the hardware raid because of the following:

- Performance (4 x 300gb SATA II in RAID 5)
- Redundancy (Raid 5, 1 drive can fail and system will be online)

I do not wish to use the Apple RAID card (very expensive), I would like to use an aftermarket one which is cheaper.

Questions:

- Does anyone have a WORKING aftermarket RAID card working in their MAC PRO (TOWER)? -(Have done some research, ROCKETRAID, need confirmation)
- If so to the above, does it work from boot?

Thanks

Comment: From what I've read, most rocketraid cards are fake raid - i.e. raid 5 is painfully slow. Sorry I know nothing about apples.

Comment: I have had a few Rocket Raid card, no problem at all... Raid 5 @ 400MB read and 320+ Write.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure (though it's hard to prove the non-existence of a solution) that there is no such option at this time.  If there were, I would definitely expect OWC to carry it, and they don't.  Only the Apple RAID card is for sure bootable.

The workaround is to get a non-bootable RAID card and put the boot drive in the second optical bay, using either the ATA connection meant for a second optical drive or a SATA connection from the motherboard (originally intended for an internal drive but now idle because you've switched the internal drives to the RAID card).  See a full solution explained [here](http://blog.macsales.com/12247-upgrade-your-06-08-mac-pro%E2%80%99s-internal-bays-to-sata-3-0).

Edit: It looks like the HighPoint RocketRAID 4321 is supposed to work. I'm afraid to try it.